# Searching multiple keywords in databases tables using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a search system but the problem is that i want to break the input string and explode it using the explode() function of php and then search each keyword in the title and description columns of the table.. Here is what i did for the single query seach

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT `name` 
            FROM texts 
            WHERE (title LIKE '%".$query."%' OR description LIKE '%".$query."%' ) ") 
            or die (mysql_error());
```

Now the problem is that i am writing the query as

```
   $query_search = explode(" ",$query);
```

now the number of keywords are unknown and i want to find it if ALL THE KEYWORDS are present in the title OR all the keywords are present in description.
Please help me out .

this is what i have tried

```
   $query_string_title = NULL ;
  $query_string_desc = NULL ;
 for($i = 0 ; $i< count($query_search) ; $i++){
     if($i == 0){
         $query_string_title .= "LIKE '%".$query_search[$i]."%'";
         $query_string_desc .= "LIKE '%".$query_search[$i]."%'";
         }
     else{
    $query_string_title .= "AND ad_title LIKE '%".$query_search[$i]."%'"; 
    $query_string_desc .= "AND description LIKE '%".$query_search[$i]."%'"; 
     }
     }
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM texts 
                                   WHERE (ad_title ".$query_string_title." 
                                   OR description ".$query_string_desc.")
                                   or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: Setup and use FULLTEXT instead

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried). With a little searching you can answer your own question easily. Just remember the `explode()` function returns an array so ask yourself what `array` functions exist that may help? Use your favorite search engine and if you're still stuck come back, tell us what you have tried and you are likely to get some help

Comment: @LawrenceCherone suggested MySQL fulltext search.  It's a scheme for searching MySQL columns for keywords.  The `LIKE '%keyword%'` approach is forever doomed to being slow even if you do get it working correctly, which is unreasonably hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do can be done like this:

```
$string = "foo john doe";

$where = 'WHERE ('. implode(') OR (',
    array_map(
        function ($word)
        {
            return 'title LIKE \'%'. $word .'%\' OR description LIKE \'%'. $word .'%\'';
        },
        explode(" ", $string))
    ) .')';

$query = "SELECT `name` FROM texts $where";

var_dump($query);
```

Howevere it doesn't seem to be the ideal way to solve your issue, have a look at FULLTEXT search as others already mentioned.

Good luck :)

EDIT 1:

If you get an error, maybe you're using an old version of php, so try:

```
function array_map_helper ($word)
{
    return 'title LIKE \'%'. $word .'%\' OR description LIKE \'%'. $word .'%\'';
}

$string = "foo john doe";

$where = 'WHERE ('. implode(') OR (', array_map('array_map_helper', explode(" ", $string)) ) .')';

$query = "SELECT `name` FROM texts $where";

var_dump($query);
```

Comment: maybe you are using an old version of php, please see my edit. Both work on my php 5.3.8